# Problems on Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Im doing some self studying on Topology, and in the chapter on metric spaces sometimes the examples just completely skips all the steps and just states the result for example one of the examples goes like this:

Consider the power set $P(\mathbb{N})$, for some set $C,D$ $\in$ $ P(\mathbb{N})$ (Note, the set of all positive even numbers, positive odd numbers, and prime numbers are examples of the members in the power set $P(\mathbb{N})$). Let us define $d(C,D)$ as:

$d(C,D)=0$, if $C=D$, and $\frac{1}{min((C-D)\cup (D-C))}$ if $C \ne D$.

Indeed $d$ is a metric and it can be shown with more effort that $d(C,E) \le \max\{d(C,D), (D,E)\}$. Then it says, can you show that $d(\mathbb{N}-C, \mathbb{N}-D)=d(C,D)?$

I am not so sure why this is the case, and have trouble showing what they ask, can anyone help me please? It will be a great help in further understanding this chapter.

Comment: In this example, $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of *strictly positive* natural numbers, right? That is, it doesn't include zero (otherwise we might divide by zero). As for your question, did you manage to show that it is a metric or do you also need help with that?

Comment: @Pedro M. Yes 0 is not included. And I am quite new to the area of topology, I mean I know what the definition of a metric is but I am still unsure on the methods to approaching these kind of problems.

Comment: It is easy to see that: $\mathbb{N}-C-(\mathbb{N}-D)=D-C$

Comment: And the metric part is simply the observation that $(C - E) \cup (E - C) \subset (C - D) \cup (D - C) \cup (E - D) \cup (D - E)$.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I guess I cant follow what that is implying. And how can we show the strong form for triangle inequality holds for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you don't have problems in justifying that

- $d(A,B) \geq 0$ and $d(A,B) = 0$ iff $A=B$.
- $d(A,B) = d(B,A)$.

From (as Pedro M. claims in his comment)
$$(A\setminus C) \cup (C \setminus A) \subseteq (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)$$
it follows that
\begin{align}
\min((A\setminus C) \cup (C \setminus A)) 
&\geq \min((A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B))\\
&= \min \{ \min((A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)), \min((B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)) \},
\end{align}
whence
$$\frac{1}{\min((A\setminus C) \cup (C \setminus A))}
\leq \max\Bigl\{ \frac{1}{\min((A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A))},
\frac{1}{\min((B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B))} \Bigr\}.$$
Therefore $d(A,C) \leq d(A,B) + d(B,C)$.

Now, from (as claimed by Peter Melech)
$$(\mathbb N \setminus C) \setminus (\mathbb N \setminus D) = D \setminus C$$
it follows that
$$C \setminus D \cup D \setminus C 
= ((\mathbb N \setminus D)\setminus(\mathbb N \setminus C)) 
\cup ((\mathbb N \setminus C)\setminus(\mathbb N \setminus D)),$$
and so,
$$\min(C \setminus D \cup D \setminus C)
=\min((\mathbb N \setminus C)\setminus(\mathbb N \setminus D) \cup
(\mathbb N \setminus D)\setminus(\mathbb N \setminus C)),$$
yielding $d(C,D) = d(\mathbb N \setminus C, \mathbb N \setminus D)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get alot from this except two parts. Why does the strong form of the inequality imply   $d(A,C)≤d(A,B)+d(B,C)?$ Also how can we actually show that $d(A,B) \ge 0? $

Comment: Also Im sorry if i may be wrong but shouldn't it be $min((C - D),(D - C))$ in the second to last line? Thank you for further assassinate.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis I don't know what you mean with *strong form*, but $$\max\{a,b\} \leq a + b,$$ for every positive numbers $a$ and $b$. So $d(A,C)\leq\max\{d(A,B,d(B,C))\}\leq d(A,B)+d(A,C)$.

Comment: $d(A,B)\geq 0$ because, by definition, $d(A,B)=0$ if $A=B$; otherwise, $d(A,B)=1/\min(S)$, where $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$, whence $\min S >0$ and thus, $d(A,B)>0$.

Comment: In the second from last line there was an error indeed, but not what you mentioned. I hope it is clear now. What do you mean with "further assassinate"?

Comment: @amsra O wow so sorry I meant assistance. With the error part, what is the error then? I would appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Actually I get it now completely. Thank you very much.